# function for checking strlen of a password doesn't work in php

Tags: php, function, string-length

I was making a sign-up page and everything worked and got send to the db but you could enter a weak pwd. I wanted to make sure that the pwd length had a minimum length of 8. I added these lines of code but when I tested it it skipped this code and you could enter any pwd you want. does anyone know why this line is getting skipped and what a sollution for this problem is?

```
function pwdTooShort($pwd) {
    $result;

    if (strlen($pwd) > 7) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';

    if(pwdTooShort($pwd) !== false)  {
        header("location: ../sign-in.php?error=passwordtooshort");
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($_GET["error"])){
    if($_GET["error"] == "passwordtooshort"){
        echo "<p> password is too short </p>";
    }
}

<form action="include/signup.inc.php" method = "post">
    <input type="password" name = "pwd" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your condition `pwdTooShort($pwd) !== false` means password too short must be `true` while your count string is > 7 is `true`. This means **abc** will be return `false` but your condition is must be `true` while **abcdefgh** will be return `true` but your condition will failed.

Comment: Try to use `mb_strlen()` instead to support multibyte characters.

Comment: You flipped true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your function name to check password too short, I think it should return `true` if too short and `false` if it is not.
Here is the code. It is just flip `true` and `false`.

```
/**
 * Check if password is too short (less than 8 characters).
 *
 * @param string $pwd The raw password without hash.
 * @return bool Return `true` if it is too short, return `false` if it is not.
 */
function pwdTooShort($pwd) {
    $result;

    if (mb_strlen($pwd) > 7) {
        $result = false;
    }
    else{
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The code above, I changed from `strlen()` to `mb_strlen()` to let it supported multi byte characters (unicode text) and exactly count the characters.
I recommend you not limit the characters to non unicode. This is recommeded by [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html).

> Allow usage of all characters including unicode and whitespace. There should be no password composition rules limiting the type of characters permitted.

The whitespace they said means between character. You can still `trim($password)`.

The rest of the code will be work fine with this.

Answer (score 2):

You have some logic issues.

Your `pwdTooShort()` will now return `true` if the password has more than 7 characters (backwards). You can change that function to:

```
function pwdTooShort($pwd)
{
    // Return true if it is 7 characters or shorter
    return mb_strlen($pwd) <= 7;
}
```

I also changed `strlen()` to `mb_strlen()` to account for multibyte characters, as @vee suggested in comments.

**Improvement suggestion**

The `if`-statement is technically correct, but is "over complicated".

You can change

```
if (pwdTooShort($pwd) !== false)
```

to either

```
if (pwdTooShort($pwd) === true)
```

or just

```
if (pwdTooShort($pwd))
```

to make it easier to read